# How to evaluate this double integral $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cos (n\pi (x+y))\text{d}x\text{d}y$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Evaluate :
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cos (n\pi (x+y))\text{d}x\text{d}y$$

Can someone please point me in the correct direction? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Also you have three differential symbols but only two integral symbols. Perhaps you meant

$$
\int_0^1\mathrm dx\int_0^1\mathrm dy\cos (n\pi (x+y))\;?
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\mathrm dx\int_0^1\mathrm dy \:\cos (n\pi (x+y)) &= \int_0^1\mathrm dx\int_0^1\mathrm dy \: [\cos{n \pi x} \cos{n \pi y} - \sin{n \pi x}\sin{n \pi y}] \\ &= \int_0^1\mathrm dx \:\cos{n \pi x} \int_0^1\mathrm dy \cos{n \pi y} - \int_0^1\mathrm dx \:\sin{n \pi x} \int_0^1\mathrm dy \sin{n \pi y} \\ &= \frac{\sin^2{n \pi} - (1-\cos{n \pi})^2}{n^2 \pi^2}\\ &= -\frac{1 -2 \cos{n \pi} + \cos{2 n \pi}}{n^2 \pi^2}\end{align}$$

Comment: How are they 0?  You are assuming that $n$ is an integer, when there is no such assumption.  Anyway, $\cos{2 \pi n} = \cos^2{n \pi} - \sin^2{n \pi}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. So you did not assume that $n$ was an integer. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int_0^1 \cos(n \pi (x + y)) dx = \frac{1}{n\pi} [\sin(n\pi(y+1)) - \sin(n\pi y)]$$

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cos(n\pi(x+y))dx dy = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{n\pi} [\sin(n\pi(y+1)) - \sin(n\pi y)] dy = \frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}(2\cos(n\pi) - 1)$$

Comment: Have you checked your result at $n=0$?